# How to center menu-item in navbar like example

Tags: reactjs, antd

Similar to the [example](https://ant.design/docs/spec/navigation#Top-Navigation) of the top navbar.

I would like to have a centered menu item and two items floated all the way to the right of the navbar.

So far I've figured out how to float the two items to the right, but I'm not sure how to center the title item. What's the `antd` way to center a menu item?

```js
<Menu mode="horizontal">
    <Menu.Item>Centered</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item style={{float:"right"}}>Right</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item style={{float:"right"}}>Right</Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! consider accepting an answer if it was helpful, Check out the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `flexbox`

```js
const centerStyle = {
  position: 'relative',
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center'
};

const rightStyle = { position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0 };

function App() {
  return (
    <Menu style={centerStyle} mode="horizontal">
      <Menu.Item> Cookies </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item> Cookies2 </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item style={rightStyle}> Right </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit laughing-minsky-7zbsh]

Comment: Thanks, this works, but when I have two elements on the rightside of the navbar, I'll have to add my own mobile-responsive code to trigger the menuoverflow. I was thinking having a centered menuitem would be a really basic usecase, does antd not have this?